# How to get the data value of 'SVG path'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I want to extract the data `d="M75.5 299.5 111.5 299.5 111.5 311.5 75.5 311.5 z"` to use it in the creation of another element.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="670px" height="400px" style="position: relative; display: block; background-color: red;">
    <g>
        <path id="k19a56d40" data-model-id="k33d3f3bd" d="M75.5 299.5 111.5 299.5 111.5 311.5 75.5 311.5 z" stroke="#cc2900" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill="#FF3300"></path>
        <path id="k67a7e77a" data-model-id="k33d3f3bd" d="M75.5 299.5 111.5 299.5 111.5 311.5 75.5 311.5 z" stroke="#cc2900" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill="url(#kcd2b6a0)"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('svg').find('path').attr('d');
```

find first one using `.eq()` and `.first()`:

```
$('svg').find('path').first().attr('d');
$('svg').find('path').eq(0).attr('d'); // <--change the index of your choice
```

`.last()` can be used if you have two paths.

Answer (score 3):

pure JavaScript

```
function(pathElemId){
var path=document.getElementById(pathElemId);
return path.getAttribute("d")
}
```

This function return "d" for path element that have pathElemId

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
$("#k19a56d40").attr("d");
```